# php refreshing only data in page

Tags: php, page-refresh

i'm a php nearby. I have a problem with my form. I connect the controller with db and extract a question and his three answers. If i click on one of this, the system return the second question, under the first question. If i click on one of the seconds answers, the system return the thirth question overwrite the second question.
I would like that second question (and its answers) overwrite the first (and its answers). How i can?
[db structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kTzB.png)
[view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kp6dV.png)

1)  index.php

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
require_once 'controllers/controller.php';
$controllers = new Controller();
$controllers->cercaDomanda(1);
$controllers->cercaRisposta(1);
$controllers->cercaNuovoId($id);
?>
```

2) Controller.php

```
<?php
require_once('models/Domanda.php');
require_once('models/Risposta.php');
require_once ('models/Model.php');

class Controller {
    public $domanda;
    public $risposta;  
    public $model;

    public function __construct(){

        $this->domande = new Domanda(); //istanziamo la classe domanda
        $this->risposte = new Risposta(); //istanziamo la classe risposta
        $this->model = new Model(); //istanziamo la classe risposta

    }

    public function cercaDomanda($id){                   

        $reslt = $this->domande->getDomanda($id);                         
        include 'views/basicView.php';  
        }   

     public function cercaRisposta($id){
         $reslt2 = $this->risposte->getRisposta($id);
         include 'views/basicView.php';  
        }

        public function cercaNuovoId($id){
            include 'views/basicView.php';  
            $reslt3 = $this->model->getIdNext();
            $reslt4 = $this->cercaDomanda($reslt3);
            $reslt5 = $this->cercaRisposta($reslt3);         
         }   
} 
?>
```

3)Domanda.php

```
<?php
require_once 'models/Domanda.php';

class Domanda {

    public function getDomanda($id){
        $dbconnection = pg_connect("host=***port=***dbname=***user=***password=***");
        $query = 'SELECT domanda FROM public."Domande" WHERE "id"='.$id;
        $result = pg_query($query); 
        return $result;
        pg_close($dbconnection);
        }
}
?>
```

4)Risposta.php

```
<?php
require_once 'models/Risposta.php';

class Risposta {

    public function getRisposta($id){
        $dbconnection = pg_connect("host=***port=***dbname=***user=***password=***");
        $query = 'SELECT * FROM public."Risposte" WHERE "id_domanda"='.$id;
        $result = pg_query($query); //or die ('Query fallita: ' .pg_last_error());
        return $result;
        pg_close($dbconnection);
    }    
}
?>
```

5)Model.php

```
<?php
require_once 'models/Model.php';

class Model {

    public function getIdNext(){

        if(isset($_POST['btnScelta'])){      
            $result = $_POST['btnScelta'];
            return $result;         
        }            
    }  
}
```

6)View

```
<html>

<head></head>

<body>

    <form action='index.php' name='chatbotyForm' method="POST">

<table>

<?php

 echo "<tr>";  
   $domanda = pg_fetch_array($reslt, null, PGSQL_ASSOC);
   print $domanda['domanda'];
   echo "</tr>";
?>

</table>    

<?php 
       while ($rispost = pg_fetch_object($reslt2)) {
            print "<td><button type='submit' name='btnScelta'    
            value='$rispost->id_domanda_successiva'>$rispost->risposta</button> 
              </td>";
             }

?>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You want to look at MySQL's `ORDER BY` clause

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I reorder rows in sql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812630/how-can-i-reorder-rows-in-sql-database)

Comment: No, i have postgresql and my problem isn't in db but in view. I call the questions and relative answers with id, there is no order.

Comment: SQL is (partially) standard, `ORDER BY` is the same in MySQL and in PostgreSQL. "There is no order" - implement one!

Comment: yes, but i don't have db problems. i have a problem of viewing. I would like the first question and it's relative answers disappear as the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view:

```
...
<?php 
   while ($rispost = pg_fetch_object($reslt2)) {
        print "<td><button type='submit' name='btnScelta'    
        value='$rispost->id_domanda_successiva'>$rispost->risposta</button> 
          </td>";
         }

?>
```

you are setting only one value in each button. which is available as `$_POST['btnScelta']` and that is used to render your last question.

**Edit** previous contents removed because they are not relevant to the question.

To render two questions pass two ids as the button value.

> To remove the first question remove the two lines from your index.php

1) index.php

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
require_once 'controllers/controller.php';
$controllers = new Controller();
/* remove the following two lines the first question wont be rendered.*/
//$controllers->cercaDomanda(1);
//$controllers->cercaRisposta(1);
$controllers->cercaNuovoId(/*$id*/);
?>
```

Now make controller process two question display.

```
class Controller {
    public function cercaNuovoId(/*$id*/){
        // include 'views/basicView.php';  
        $reslt3 = $this->model->getIdNext();
        // render previous question only if a value exists.
        if ($result3) {
          list($current, $previous) = explode(',', $result3);
          $this->cercaDomanda($previous);
          $this->cercaRisposta($previous);
        }
        // show the first question on first visit.
        if (empty($current)){
          $current = 1;
        }
        $reslt4 = $this->cercaDomanda($current);
        $reslt5 = $this->cercaRisposta($current);
     }
}
```

Now in the view make modification for button to have two values seperated by comma. current question id is available as $id from `Controller::cercaRisposta()`

```
<?php 
   while ($rispost = pg_fetch_object($reslt2)) {
        print "<td><button type='submit' name='btnScelta'    
        value='{$rispost->id_domanda_successiva},{id}'>$rispost->risposta</button> 
          </td>";
         }
?>
</form>
```

you can also pass the previous question id by changing form's action property with a query like `index.php?previous=$id`.

Comment: Thanks for all! But this non change my problem. The first question and it's relative questions do not disappear. I leave the db structure in post.

Comment: reading through the comments in question, I realize my understanding of your question was not correct. Let me know when you click `liceo scientifico` whether you want to show  the third question `Di dove sei?` and its answers(relative questions?) only OR both second and third question with its answers and not show first question.

Comment: I would like that second question (and its answers)  overwrite the first (and its answers). Sorry for delay

Comment: Alright, The answer is updated for that. Please verify.

Comment: A typo in `cercaNuovoId` instead of `$reslt3` I wrote `$result3`.

Comment: Okay! It works! there is a error in controller. I have to parse    ($str = "$reslt3";) and change the explode  (  explode(",", $str);   ). Thanks for everything!